# Supabase PSQL row level security policy for update vs insert

Tags: psql, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

I have a `workspaces` and `profiles_workspaces` (cols = worspace_id, profile_id) table and want to implement a soft-delete, so `workspaces` has a `is_deleted` boolean column. So for deletion I'd just do an update call to `workspaces` to set `is_deleted` to `true`.

The `SELECT` policy on `workspaces` is `USING (id IN (SELECT profiles_workspaces.workspace_id FROM profiles_workspaces) AND is_deleted is FALSE)` to allow users to only see non-deleted workspaces they are added to.

The `UPDATE` policy is simply `true` for both `USING` and `CHECK` since for now I'm good to let someone update as long as they can see it.

When I set that `is_deleted` bool on a workspace row manually in the DB all is good. The client doesn't see that workspace anymore. However, when I want to "delete" a workspace supabase won't perform the update, saying it violates a RLS policy.

When I remove the `AND is_deleted is FALSE` from the `SELECT` policy I can do updates no problem.

So my question is: How do I allow people to update the `is_deleted` field to `true` without letting them see workspaces where `is_deleted` is true? I know I can just filter the supabase select statement but then a user could just hit the API directly and see "deleted" workspaces they were added on to before by altering the API payload, so not letting those rows be seen via RLS seems far more simple.

### Edit: Full Policy Statements:

#### workspaces - select

```sql
create policy "Enable SELECT for the workspace their user is added to"
on "public"."workspaces"
as permissive
for select
to authenticated
USING (id IN (SELECT profiles_workspaces.workspace_id FROM profiles_workspaces) AND is_deleted is FALSE)
```

#### workspaces - update

```sql
create policy "Enable UPDATE for the workspace their user is added to" 
on "public"."workspaces"
as permissive 
for update
to authenticated
using (true) with check (true);
```

#### profiles_workspaces - select

```sql
create policy "Enable SELECT for the workspace list their user is added to"
on "public"."profiles_workspaces"
as permissive
for select
to authenticated
using (
    (profile_id = (auth.jwt()->>'sub')::uuid)
);
```

### Table schemas

#### workspaces

- id uuid
- name varchar(255)
- slug varchar(255)
- is_deleted boolean default false

#### profiles_workspaces

- profile_id uuid
- workspace_id uuid

And the `profiles.id` is the same as supabase's `auth.users.id`, in case anyone's wondering about the select policy for `profiles_workspaces`.

### EDIT 2 Workaround

Looks like it's a PSQL bug (thank you [LaurenzAlbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe)!). So here's a workaround that does the trick. Not super clean but it works.

1. I added the `is_visible` boolean column to `workspaces`
2. Replace `is_deleted IS FALSE` in the SELECT policy with `is_visible IS TRUE`
3. Add this function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_workspace_deletion()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER set search_path = public
AS $function$
    begin
        IF new.is_deleted is true and old.is_visible is true then
        update public.workspaces set is_visible = false where id = new.id;
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
$function$
;
```

4. Add trigger

```sql
create trigger on_workspace_deleted
  after update on public.workspaces
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_workspace_deletion();
```

Note it has to be AFTER update not BEFORE. When I tried the function to run on BEFORE UPDATE (with the `THEN` being `new.is_visible = false;`) I would get the same RLS policy error when trying to update `is_deleted` on a workspace. However the `AFTER UPDATE` function works!

Comment: Thank you for looking into it @LaurenzAlbe! I found a workaround in the meantime... I'll add it to the question body for now in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was myself surprised that a `FOR SELECT` policy should be used to check new rows and cause an error, so [I asked the mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/aee893f1ec3ca8f62a0da2fc2f9f8b73920f9f9d.camel%40cybertec.at).  It seems that this behavior is intentional, and the reasons given were

- it would be surprising if you could perform an `UPDATE`, but the updated row version seemingly vanished, so row level security should prevent that
- if you could update a row so that you can no longer see the new version, you could trigger a constraint conflict with a row that you cannot see, which allowed you to gain information about those invisible rows

You will have to use a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. While I personally disagree with the first point (IMO you should be able to update a row while you can see it, and you could even get a response telling  you if the update went through. However, not being able to see it AFTER the update feels off to me). That being said, I can understand and sympathize with the second reason far more. It could be an admittedly somewhat obtuse but still very real attack vector. Although I'd argue that if if you can't see invisible rows you'd likely at most get some metadata like number of rows (between rows even maybe). Thank you!